# Conditional Dataframe Grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find the mean of Walmart and Food Lion's mean by each month, but am getting HEBs revenue data included in the group by down below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['1960-01-01','1960-01-01','1960-01-01','1960-02-01','1960-02-01','1960-02-01',
                            '1961-01-01','1961-01-01','1961-01-01','1961-02-01','1961-02-01','1961-02-01'],
                   'Company': ['HEB', 'Walmart', 'Food Lion','HEB', 'Walmart', 'Food Lion',
                              'HEB', 'Walmart', 'Food Lion','HEB', 'Walmart', 'Food Lion'],
                   'Revenue': [200, 800, 400, 400, 300, 600, 400, 400, 900, 900, 800, 600]})

print(df)
```

Output:

```
              date    Company  Revenue
    0   1960-01-01        HEB    200
    1   1960-01-01    Walmart    800
    2   1960-01-01  Food Lion    400
    3   1960-02-01        HEB    400
    4   1960-02-01    Walmart    300
    5   1960-02-01  Food Lion    600
    6   1961-01-01        HEB    400
    7   1961-01-01    Walmart    400
    8   1961-01-01  Food Lion    900
    9   1961-02-01        HEB    900
    10  1961-02-01    Walmart    800
    11  1961-02-01  Food Lion    600
```

I am trying not to include HEBs data in this `groupby`. How do I do this?

```
df.groupby('date')['Revenue'].mean()
```

```
date
1960-01-01    466.666667
1960-02-01    433.333333
1961-01-01    566.666667
1961-02-01    766.666667
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. Perhaps the easiest is to simply exclude 'HEB' from the data you are grouping by:

```
df[df.Company != "HEB"].groupby("date")["Revenue"].mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

To get individual companies you can use

```
df = df[df['Company'] == 'Walmart']

print(df)
          date    Company  Revenue
1   1960-01-01    Walmart    800
4   1960-02-01    Walmart    300
7   1961-01-01    Walmart    400
10  1961-02-01    Walmart    800
```

If you want to exclude a company you can use

```
df = df[df['Company'] != 'HEB']

print(df)
          date    Company  Revenue
1   1960-01-01    Walmart    800
2   1960-01-01  Food Lion    400
4   1960-02-01    Walmart    300
5   1960-02-01  Food Lion    600
7   1961-01-01    Walmart    400
8   1961-01-01  Food Lion    900
10  1961-02-01    Walmart    800
11  1961-02-01  Food Lion    600
```